# How to Keep track of tab opened from the main page?

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

I'm new to web development and I'm finding my way through it.

I have the following situation:

User Logs into the web-app. He/She will be presented with four different module links on his console.

When userA clicks on one of the links , a new TAB will be opened and allows userA to make changes/work/ in that module. When userA is working on that particular module, it will be checked-out to UserA, and all other users will see that **UserA is accessing the module** on their consoles and inaccessible to all others.

Now, when user closes/logs-out of the module(tab), the status of the module in all the user consoles should be changed to "accessible".

I choose **MEAN stack** to implement this application.

Question:

How to handle the situation:

When user closes/logs-out of the module(tab), the status of the module in all the user consoles should be changed to "accessible".

How to keep track of the tab opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like the most appropriate solution for something like this would be using sockets. (You can try [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/), but there are others libraries for websockets as well)

The main reason for this, is that we want to keep track of a disconnection event. This requires some kind of polling from the server/client. How much you want to do with the sockets is of course up to you; it's possible to keep the state of accessible modules stored in a map, and update them when you get a GET to an accessible module. Likewise, you can also use the socket with the 'connect' event, giving you the possibility of realtime updates.

When the user then closes the module, a disconnection event is sent such that you can change it to accessible.

Comment: Thanks @andreas for the suggestion. Implementation completed with socket.io